# Paint Bucket Cursor?

Tags: windows, cursors

I'm not sure if this is the right site to ask, but I'm looking for Aero's Paint Bucket cursor. It's not in `C:\Windows\Cursors\`, but Paint certainly has an Aero-styles paint bucket cursor.

Thanks in advance, and again: Sorry if this is the wrong site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [Resource Extract](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/resources_extract.html) on the file `C:\Windows\System32\mspaint.exe`, the cursor should be embedded in that executable.

BTW, I'm not sure you can use it freely once extracted (I mean for licensing problem...)

Comment: Thanks, I extracted it and it works fine in my application. The application probably won't be released publicly any time soon, but I will seek for some licensing information with Microsoft when the time comes.

Answer (score 2):

The paint bucket cursor of Paint is just a black and white version of the paint bucket toolbar button icon. It is most probably included in paint itself and is likely to be compiled into the executable as a resource.

Comment: Actually, MSPaint in Windows 7 has an Aero icon, not black and white.

Comment: And what it aero about it? It had a gradient? That's been possible since Window 3.11 I think. I'm running Windows 7 here, but I don't see anything special about the cursor.

Comment: Sorrry, I was a little confused there. Afaik, in Windows XP, there was a paint bucket icon with only 2 pure black and white colors. In C# you can only load icons that are purely black and white using `new Cursor(String Filename)`. Ofcourse, there's other ways.

Comment: You sure? I don't use C#, but colored (and even animated) cursors have been a part of Windows for (almost) as long as I remember. I can't imagine C# will only let you load black and white cursors.